# How many items is feasible in the "IN" clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We've installed some database monitoring software. One of the `sql` statements than brought our system to a halt was the following:

```
update StockItems set WebTransfer='N'
where stockcode in ('1001','1002','1003',......)
```

`where "......"` above represents `2496` other stock codes! i.e. in total there were `2499` stock codes listed.

This is in a solution given to us by one of our software vendors.

I'm not surprised that it cause the `SQL` engine to hemorrhage, and to my mind it should either join to another table to obtain the list of codes to update, or just go ahead and update all of them (which I think in this case would be ok).

While I know that I'd never write SQL like that, and I've never seen anything like it, I'm not sure exactly which convention/standard would support my view that it's not a good solution.

Can anyone offer any advice on what to go back to the vendors with?

Comment: Perhaps the values could be put in a temporary table/table variable and joined to source table.

Comment: I've seen queries with ~2.5k values in an IN clause, but they were parameters. e.g. `IN ( @p0, @p1, @p2 ... )` and it worked just fine. What's the problem? Does the query take a long time to generate a plan? Does it take a long time to find the records in the clustered index to update because your disks are slow to read or there's no index on `StockCode` so you do a clustered index scan? Does the clustered index take a long time to update because your disks are slow to write?

Comment: I'm not sure. Our DBA emailed it to me for feedback as it was causing some issue but I'm not entirely sure what that issue was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [maximum size is about 10k values in the IN clause.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). You can better use some temp tables and then use JOINS to get the data

You can also check the similar problem reported [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288095).

Answer (score 0):

In my openion Better to use a different table to store all the ID's and use JOINS to update the table.

Or you can use an INNER QUERY like this

```
update StockItems set WebTransfer='N'
where stockcode in (Select * from Temp where ID>=1001 && ID<=END);
```

Comment: Thanks - that's definitely how I'd do it. Intuitively it's the efficient way, but it would be great to have something definitive to go back to the vendor with other than "I prefer that you do it this other way".